# QGIS Calculating Line Lengths and Statistics

Tags: qgis, analysis, tools

I am working through this tutorial:

http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/calculating_line_lengths.html

In the tutorial we import a shapefile map of railroads,clip the data through a selection/calculation to create a new layer. Next we add a new field to this new shapefile table using Field Calculator.

Everything was working until I got to steps 18 and 19 when I need to SUM up the length of all the values in the field.

I am using a later version (2.18.3) So my steps for this process are  Vector>Analysis Tools>Basic Statistics for Numeric Fields.

In the Basic Statistics For Numeric Fields dialog box I am able to select the layer, but I am unable to select the field 'length_km2' I think the problem is that the field is the wrong type. The field I need is currently set to 'double' in the table. The type name is 'Real'. I think the type should be 'Real' or 'Integer'. Is there a way to edit the field type? Or is there another way to apply this calculation?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Another quick method is to open up the **Field Calculator** for your layer and simply enter the expression: `sum("fieldName")`. This will show you the sum value in the preview (ofcourse you don't have to create a new field or anything).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field type as 'double' is correct and it should show up in the dropdown menu of *Field to calculate statistics on*. I tried on the same dataset as yours on the same version of QGIS and I did not encounter any problem.

An alternate way to do it would be to use *Statistics Panel*. You can access it by clicking on '*Show statistical summary*' button near the select options and Field Calculator buttons on top -
[image: Show statistical summary]

The *'Statistics Panel'* should show up on along with the panels on the left -
[image: Statistics Panel]

Comment: Thanks for showing me the Statistics Panel option. I was able to get 'basic statistics for numeric fields' to work by adding a .cvst to the same directory. At least I think that is why it is now working!